# DynamoDB ProjectionExpression exclude attribute (all fields except one)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement where my dynamodb table has many attributes, and i need all of them in the projection expression except one or two columns which i dont need in response. (I am scanning the table).
Is there a way how can i define this in ProjectionExpression (all except this one column).
I have seen examples where ProjectionExpression only takes what all "is required" and not the other way.

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation, this is not possible:

> ProjectionExpression - A string that identifies one or more attributes
>   to retrieve from the table. These attributes can include scalars,
>   sets, or elements of a JSON document. The attributes in the expression
>   must be separated by commas. If no attribute names are specified, then
>   all attributes will be returned.

Here is a link to help you better undestand what goes underneath the ProjectionExpression: https://medium.com/pageup-tech/dynamodb-and-projection-expressions-why-c08c40243195