# Set Projection expression in DynamoDB to EXCLUDE columns

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am constructing queries in DynamoDB and want to display ***all but a particular set of columns***.

I see that [Projection Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) can be used, but from what is written, we need to specify all the columns which need to be displayed as result. The reason is because there are too many columns specified in our table (more than 100) to list down individually.

My use case is like this:

Imagine a table like:

```
|ID     |Name     |Age     |Address      |.....
|1      |Student1 |15      |Oak View, XYZ|.....
```

My result should be like:

```
|ID     |Name     |Address      |.....
|1      |Student1 |Oak View, XYZ|.....
```

Here my expression is set to ***exclude the 'Age' column***

Please help.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473393/dynamodb-projectionexpression-exclude-attribute-all-fields-except-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to explicitly exclude attributes from projection, in practice if you want to omit 1 column out of 10 it's easier to just pop those columns from DynamoDB's response in your code.